# how to import private key without scaning QR code

Tags: private-key-import

I bought Bitcoins from the ATM and it gave me a receipt with a QR code.
and now after one year i wanted to scan it into my wallet, but ink on paper faded and it can`t be scaned.....
so im wondering if i can enter the private key manualy by keyboard?

Comment: What wallet do you use? Bitcoin-Core? `importpivkey` would work on Bitcoin-Core if your private key is WIF encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Your QR code contains your private key, but yes you can recover with the private key directly if the QR code is now physically damaged.

I do not see that option for blockchain.info (which you stated you are trying to use in your comment):

https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet supports QR codes Bitcoin-Qt (wallet.dat) and blockchain.info (wallet.aes.json) files.

Try one these methods instead (or choose another wallet which you prefer):

http://themerkle.com/how-to-recover-your-bitcoins-from-blockchain-info-using-electrum/

https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_importingPrivateKeys.html

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Help:How_to_import_private_keys_in_Bitcoin_Core_0.7%2B

Comment: yes QR code is damaged, but private key that is  writen bellow QR code it`s still readable. 
so where can i enter this key manually in my blockchain wallet

Answer (score 0):

No need to re-invent the wheel for [importing or sweeping paper wallets](http://www.xbteller.com/paper-wallets) for mobile wallets such as airBitz, Blockchain, and Mycelium.  The Jaxx wallet also supports sweeping paper wallets under (Tools)->(Transfer Paper Wallet). These wallets should allow one to type a paper wallet's private keys if QR codes can't be scanned.

Comment: Actually the latest version of the Jaxx wallet says "coming soon" where this manual-key-entering functionality is supposed to be. So, no. Currently it is QR only.